# Serializing a class with a generic Enum that can be different Enum types

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

I'm trying to design an application that will allow the user to specify an Enum type in an XML, and from that the application will execute a specific method tied to that enum (using a dictionary). I'm getting hung up on the Enum portion of the XML.

```
public class TESTCLASS
{
    private Enum _MethodType;

    [XmlElement(Order = 1, ElementName = "MethodType")]
    public Enum MethodType
    {
        get { return _MethodType; }
        set { _MethodType = value; } 
    }
    public TESTCLASS() { }

    public TESTCLASS(Enummies.BigMethods bigM)
    {
        MethodType = bigM;
    }
    public TESTCLASS(Enummies.SmallMethods smallM)
    {
        MethodType = smallM;
    }
}

public class Enummies
{
    public enum BigMethods { BIG_ONE, BIG_TWO, BIG_THREE }
    public enum SmallMethods { SMALL_ONE, SMALL_TWO, SMALL_THREE }
}
```

And then trying to serialize the TESTCLASS results in an exception:

```
string p = "C:\\testclass.xml";
TESTCLASS testclass = new TESTCLASS(Enummies.BigMethods.BIG_ONE);
TestSerializer<TESTCLASS>.Serialize(p, testclass);

System.InvalidOperationException: The type Enummies+BigMethods may not be used in this context.
```

My serialization method looks like this:

```
public class TestSerializer<T> where T: class
{
    public static void Serialize(string path, T type)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type.GetType());
        using (var writer = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, type);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize(string path)
    {
        T type;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            type = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

I tried including some checking/casting in the MethodType Getter, but this results in the same error.

```
    public Enum MethodType
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_MethodType is Enummies.BigMethods) return (Enummies.BigMethods)_MethodType; 
            if (_MethodType is Enummies.SmallMethods) return (Enummies.SmallMethods)_MethodType;
            throw new Exception("UNKNOWN ENUMMIES TYPE");
        }
        set { _MethodType = value; } 
    }
```

Comment: Do you know in advance what enum types might be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to serialize your class with `XmlSerializer`, the innermost exception I get is:

```
Message="System.Enum is an unsupported type. Please use [XmlIgnore] attribute to exclude members of this type from serialization graph."
```

This is self-explanatory: you cannot serialize a member whose type is the abstract type [`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx).

You can, however, serialize a member of type `System.Object` **provided that all possible types of value that might be encountered are declared statically by using [`[XmlInclude(typeof(T))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx).**  Thus you can modify your type as follows:

```
// Include all possible types of Enum that might be serialized
[XmlInclude(typeof(Enummies.BigMethods))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Enummies.SmallMethods))]
public class TESTCLASS
{
    private Enum _MethodType;

    // Surrogate object property for MethodObject required by XmlSerializer
    [XmlElement(Order = 1, ElementName = "MethodType")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public object MethodTypeObject
    {
        get { return MethodType; }
        set { MethodType = (Enum)value; }
    }

    // Ignore the Enum member that cannot be serialized directly
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Enum MethodType
    {
        get { return _MethodType; }
        set { _MethodType = value; }
    }
    public TESTCLASS() { }

    public TESTCLASS(Enummies.BigMethods bigM)
    {
        MethodType = bigM;
    }
    public TESTCLASS(Enummies.SmallMethods smallM)
    {
        MethodType = smallM;
    }
}
```

And XML will be generated as follows:

```
<TESTCLASS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MethodType xsi:type="BigMethods">BIG_THREE</MethodType>
</TESTCLASS>
```

Or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TESTCLASS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MethodType xsi:type="SmallMethods">SMALL_TWO</MethodType>
</TESTCLASS>
```

Notice the `xsi:type` attribute?  That is a [W3C standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) that an element may use to explicitly assert its type.  Microsoft uses this attribute to represent type information for polymorphic elements as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuhlAm).

You might want to check that the value type is a known `Enum` type in the setter for `MethodObject` (rather than the getter) but this is not required for XML serialization.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize you can serialize members of System.Object as long as you specify the potential types in XmlIncludes. I wonder why I was getting a different exception than what you saw. Also, are these attributes necessary? I've never seen them before. "[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]"

Comment: @TalenKylon - those attributes aren't necessary.  They keep the surrogate property from showing up in the debugger and property editor.  The exception I listed was the innermost attribute rather than the outer attribute.  Also, I added the `[XmlInclude(typeof(Enummies.BigMethods))]` attributes before testing serialization.