# c# XmlSerializer List of typed objects

Tags: c#, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have the problem that I got xml from a REST service and have to deserialize it to an object structure and there is a type="proglang" in it.

```
<listResult>
   <listEntry xsi:type="proglang">
      <id>0</id>
      <name>C#</name>
   </listEntry>
   <listEntry xsi:type="proglang">
      <id>0</id>
      <name>C#</name>
   </listEntry>
</listResult>
```

How should the object model with the xml attributes look like in c#?

My Code so far:

```
[XmlRoot("listResult")]
public class ListResult
{
    [XmlElement("listEntry")]
    //[XmlArrayItem(Type=typeof(proglang))]
    public List<proglang> listEntry;
}

public class proglang
{
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public int id;
    [XmlElement("label")]
    public string name;
}
```

and the resulting XML from serializing:

```
<listResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <listEntry>
    <code>1</code>
    <label>C#</label>
  </listEntry>
  <listEntry>
    <code>1</code>
    <label>C++</label>
  </listEntry>
</listResult>
```

Comment: Can you show us your existing C# code?

Comment: So the REST service xml doesn't declare the `xsi` namespace?

Comment: no xsi available, but its a class with an id and a name.

Comment: That XML is syntactically invalid.  The namespace with prefix `xsi` is never declared.  Upload to http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will see the error `Line 2 Column 35: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "listEntry" is not bound.`  Is your really invalid, or did you simply omit the `xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` attribute when typing the XML into the question?

Comment: If the XML were valid, you could introduce a surrogate psuedo-polymorphic `object []` array property along the lines of the single-object surrogate property in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43955876/3744182).  But if the XML is really invalid that won't help at all.